# Meep C++ interface benchmark

Tags: electromagnetism

I am having trouble getting a good parallelization with FDTD simulations in Meep. Originally, I tried to use the Python interface on a rather big computing cluster, but the runtime of my simulations did not change appreciably upon changing the number of cores for parallelization. I know that this might have a lot of reasons.

I thought that maybe going to the C++ interface might improve the parallelization performance, so I set up Meep on my own Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 21. I copied the benchmark test-script (https://github.com/NanoComp/meep/blob/master/tests/bench.cpp), compiled using g++ and then ran the script via mpirun with a varying number of cores. Again: No speedup.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this expected behavior?
Are there any known tricks from your side about how to improve the performance or scaling behavior  of meep simulations?

Benchmark results for 3x3x3 simulation
1 core: 1.04605 seconds, 2 cores: 1.12921 second, 3 cores: 1.16467 seconds, 4 cores: 1.17204 seconds

Comment: Would Computational Science be a better place for this. It isn’t a physics question .

Comment: just a thought but...is your simulation too small to expect any gains from parallelization? are all the other overheads dominating your simulation time?

Comment: This is a question for the MEEP-specific forums. You're not going to get answers here -- most people here will have no idea what MEEP actually is (including me).

Answer (score 0):

The raspberry pi might have a CPU thats effectively single core. Changing the MPI rank will not yield runtime improvements if that is the case. I'd advise to repeat the benchmark on a multicore CPU.